# Sitecore 9 Form Module vs WFFM

Tags: wffm, sitecore-forms

I have seen that Sitecore 9 introduced new forms. Can anyone help me get information how these forms are different from WFFM?

Any help for these new forms will be helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WFFM and Sitecore forms are quite different in their implementation and the user interface for managing the forms in Sitecore. Both provide a fairly full-featured form building module. Sitecore forms however is a lot slicker to use as a content editor and is built in a much more modern way.

However given that it’s still quite new functionally there are some key differences/limitations worth highlighting:

- Sitecore forms does not have CAPTCHA, file upload, telephone or credit card fields but WFFM does
- It is not possible to verify a form when it is submitted or set the custom error message on a per-field basis out of the box with Sitecore forms
- More steps are required to add custom fields for Sitecore forms but it’s arguably more extensible and flexible to customise and more inline with modern approaches
- There are only 5 submit / save actions in Sitecore forms vs 16 in WFFM. Send email being one of the key ones missing in 9.0 but now available out of the box in 9.01 and above (making 6 submit actions).
- There is currently no rules engine support for Sitecore 9 forms but there is for WFFM
- There are no CRM connectors for Sitecore forms out of the box but WFFM has MS Dynamics save actions etc.
- Sitecore forms has tracking/analytics at a field level where as WFFM only does this at form level so this is once area where it wins out.

**Sitecore Forms 9.1 features:**

- Allows you to use conditions in form elements and build forms that respond to user input and show relevant questions. WFFM does not support this.
- You can now put forms in folders and control security on access.
- Provides support for value providers to pre-fill form fields.

In short I think which is best for your project depends on what you are doing but I think if you don’t use WFFM currently and are looking to build new forms then go with the new Sitecore Forms module as WFFM has now been phased out. It should be easy enough to build in anything you need that is missing in Sitecore forms and there are some community created fields and submit actions out there that you can use e.g:  http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/category/sitecore-forms-extensions/.

Web Forms For Marketers was deprecated in Sitecore XP 9.1 and is also not supported in Sitecore XP 9.2.
9.0.2 is the last release where WFFM can be used.

This post from Joao is a really good in-depth overview of the differences which I’d recommend reading:

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/joaoneto.blog/2017/11/22/is-it-time-to-migrate-my-wffm-forms-to-sitecore-forms/amp/